# How to use the MediaStore api to retreive a song and play it? Also, get its cover art and if possible get read its input stream?

Tags: android, kotlin, filenotfoundexception, mediastore

```
package com.devrj.helium.data_model

import android.content.ContentUris.withAppendedId
import android.content.Context
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.CancellationSignal
import android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.*
import com.devrj.helium.model.entity.TrackEntity

class MediaStoreDataStream(streamInfo: () -> Context) :
    DataStream<Context, TrackEntity>(streamInfo) {

    private var cancellationSignal: CancellationSignal? = null

    companion object {
        private const val COL_ID = 0
        private const val COL_TITLE = 1
        private const val COL_SIZE = 2
        private const val COL_ARTIST = 3
        private const val COL_ALBUM = 4
        private const val COL_YEAR = 5
        private const val COL_TRACK = 6
        private const val COL_DATE_MODIFIED = 7
        private const val COL_DATE_ADDED = 8
        private const val COL_DISPLAY_NAME = 9
        private const val COL_DATA = 10

        val projection = arrayOf(
            _ID,
            TITLE,
            SIZE,
            ARTIST,
            ALBUM,
            YEAR,
            TRACK,
            DATE_MODIFIED,
            DATE_ADDED,
            DISPLAY_NAME,
            DATA
        )
    }

    override fun stopStream() {
        super.stopStream()
        cancellationSignal?.cancel()
    }


    override fun onStreamStarted() {
        val context = streamInfo()


        val contentResolver = context.contentResolver

        cancellationSignal = CancellationSignal()

        val trackQuery = contentResolver.query(
            EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            cancellationSignal
        )
        trackQuery?.use { cursor ->
            /*
            Cache column indices
             */
            val columns = Array(projection.size) { i ->
                cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[i])
            }
            /*
            Per entity
             */
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                val columnId = cursor.getLong(columns[COL_ID])

                val locationURI: Uri = withAppendedId(INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columnId)


                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                //////////////////CREATE NEW ENTITY/////////////////
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                val newTrack = TrackEntity(columnId)

                newTrack.apply {
                    uri = locationURI.path.toString()
                    size = cursor.getLong(columns[COL_SIZE])
                    title = cursor.getString(columns[COL_TITLE])
                    artist = cursor.getString(columns[COL_ARTIST])
                    album = cursor.getString(columns[COL_ALBUM])
                    track = cursor.getInt(columns[COL_TRACK])
                    dateModified = cursor.getLong(columns[COL_DATE_MODIFIED])
                    dateAdded = cursor.getLong(columns[COL_DATE_ADDED])
                    dateAccessed = cursor.getLong(columns[COL_DATE_ADDED])
                    year = cursor.getLong(columns[COL_YEAR])
                    displayName = cursor.getString(columns[COL_DISPLAY_NAME])
                    filePath = cursor.getString(columns[COL_DATA])
                }

                send(newTrack)

                newTrack.deb()

            }
        }

    }


}
```

I recently started learning about the MediaStore API, and since I'm building a music player app I thought it would be beneficial to migrate to it due to all the performance benefits.
However, I can't seem to play a single song or retrieve its cover art. How can I achieve this?

This is how I try to play the song

```
            val resolver: ContentResolver = onContextRequest!!.onRequest().contentResolver
            val mode = "rw"

            try {

                val uri = Uri.parse(Stem.get().loadedTrack.data!!.uri)

                uri.toast(onContextRequest!!.onRequest())

                resolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, mode).use {

                    player!!.setDataSource(it!!.fileDescriptor)
                }

            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                "ERROR $e".longToast(onContextRequest!!.onRequest())
            }
```

And I get the exception, FileNotFoundException

```
ERROR java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /internal/audio/<some_id>
```

Before I could just set the data source to the file's path, and it worked fine, but this method is not the most efficient.

In the official android documentation, it states how to do it. Which is what I'm doing.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#open-file

These are all the permissions I have declared (yes they are being granted at runtime)

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what `EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`is. If You are using Android Q then use

```
Uri mediaUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
```

Then build file's `ContentUri`like

```
contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, _id);
```

Take this uri to start MediaMetaRetriever to get the albumart

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
byte[] img = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
```

You can play this uri like

```
mMediaplayer.setDataSource(mContext, uri);
```

Hope that helps.
Don't forget to set running permissions.

GGK

Comment: I'm not using Android Q :'(

Comment: This is the URI that I get when I use ContentUris.withAppendedId(EXTERNA_CONTENT_URI, _id)

Comment: location URI path -> /external/audio/media/60036

Comment: that's the same path that I use for the media player

Comment: If You can't find the file, then the file doesn't exist on that place or You don't have reading permissioin on it. check this.

Comment: "FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /internal/audio/<some_id>" says, that Your are searching in the `INTERNAL_STORAGE`, thats the storage of YOUR app, You have to use `EXTERNAL_STORAGE` if You want do fetch not in Your Apps directory